# How to tell when something is done rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, apexcharts

I have a bunch of charts rendering at once (~20-30)
I want them to render more like in chunks of 5.

Is there a way to tell when the first batch is done rendering so I can set the second batch to begin?

Comment: so, you want to know when the charts have been [mounted](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#mounted)?

Comment: Wow, that looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: Turns out it doesn't actually wait until the rendering is done... So my charts just all render at once still...

Comment: or perhaps you're using it wrong